# Symfony2 - form_start function customise in twig

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

Form helpers `form_start` and `form_end` are useful in twig:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I can customise some parameters like the `method` or the `action`. But I need to customise others parameters like the `class` or add the `form-enctype`.

Can I do it? Should i set up it into the `FormType.php`?

Since now I simply try to add my customised value to the `twig` function like below:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'class': 'myclass', 'action': 'myaction'}) }}
// fields...
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': true}) }}
```

But in this case, for example, the `class` does not appear.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As `form_start` has the [following signature](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-start-view-variables),

```
form_start(view, variables)
```

And as `class` doesn't represent a valid variable name. You need to specify your class as a `key/value` array using the `attr` attribute.

**Then, try ...**

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': 'myaction', 'attr': {'class': 'your_class_name'}}) }}
```

**Also ...**

- You should be sure that your Type fileds are well defined in order to let the `form_start` helper set the right `form-enctype`.
- The `form_enctype(formView)` helper is deprecated since Symfony 2.3.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution works perfectly.
Then, i don't have to use the `form-enctype` also whether i have the files upload because the `form_start()` set up automatically the `form-enctype'. That's correct? However into the form tags i don't see it.

Comment: Why `class` is duplicated in the `variables` array?

Comment: The proposed code snippet is in contrary to your explanation, as you have put `class` as a variable!

Comment: Should be `{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'your-class'} }) }}`

Comment: same is true for `id`.  It must also go in the `attr` array.